# VideoJS event for leaving page

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am using VideoJS with a custom script that posts values back to a database via AJAX. When a video is paused it PUTs the percentage of the video watched to the database.

This all works great except for one thing. If they just leave the page while watching the video it doesn't record the point where they left.

From my research it looks like I should be using window.onbeforeunload to update the paused_at field but I can't figure out how to create a custom listener.

Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    videojs("video" + videoId, {
        // Video player options
        "controls":true,
        "autoplay":false,
        "preload": "auto",
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "400px"
    }).ready(function() {

    // Bring our object into scope
    var video = this;

    // Time that they start watching the video
    var started_at = function() {
        var video_percent = calc_percent(video.currentTime(), video.duration());
        var data = {
            "id": videoId,
            "user": userId,
            "started_at": video_percent
        };
        ajax_post(data);
    };

    // Video was paused
    var paused_at = function() {
        var video_percent = calc_percent(video.currentTime(), video.duration());

        var data = {
            "id": videoId,
            "user": userId,
            "paused_at": video_percent
        };
        ajax_post(data);
    };

    // Video is completed
    var finished_at = function() {
        var data = {
            "id": videoId,
            "user": userId,
            "finished_at": true
        };
        ajax_post(data);
    };

    // Post our data to the update route
    var ajax_post = function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '/videoAPI',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data
        });
    };

    var calc_percent = function(progress, total) {
        var percent = (progress / total) * 100;

        return percent.toFixed(2);
    }

    // Listen for event and fire the right method
    video.on("play", started_at);
    video.on("pause", paused_at);
    video.on("ended", finished_at);
    window.onbeforeunload = paused_at;

    });
});
```

Can I create a custom event listener to PUT the current percentage of video watched when they leave the page?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance that look like it should work. Instead of `window.onbeforeunload = paused_at;` you might try a jquery event listener.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', paused_at);
```

Comment: I have tried a few variations on this.


   ` $(window).on('unload', paused_at); `
`    $(window).on('beforeunload', paused_at); `
`    $(window).unload(paused_at); `

While they do fire the event. No data is written to the database. Could it possibly be skipping the ajax function?